# How to implement glfx.js or vintage.js to my website?

Tags: javascript

How to implement these scripts into my website? Should i write something down in index.html and something else or just upload these zip folders from glfx and vintage websites into mine?

Comment: You need to add a `<script>` tag to your HTML with an appropriate `src` attribute, but if you're struggling with that, how are you going to handle the coding required to use these libraries?

Comment: there are some default image effects already made, no need for more coding. Thanks for answer!:)

Comment: I think you'll find there's rather more to it than that.